# the format time on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to know how to recuperate the format **time** on my form please? 
For example start_time => 20:00 and end_time 22:00.

In my **table course** I have this

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('course', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->date('date_seance');
            $table->time('start_time');
            $table->time('end_time');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Then, on my **model course** I have this

```
class Course extends Model
{
    //
    protected $dates = ['date_seance', 'start_time', 'end_time'];
}
```

In my **view index.blade**

```
@foreach($course as $item)
<tr>
   <td> {{$item->date_seance->format('d/m/Y') }}</td>
   <td> {{$item->start_time}}</td>
   <td> {{$item->end_time}}</td>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by `recuperate`? Do you want a specific output? If so, what output are you looking for?

Comment: @Jerodev: Sorry, yes for example start_time => 20:00 and end_time 22:00

Comment: Like `{{$item->start_time->format('h:s')}}`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @Jerodev I guess he meant have/get.. or more explicitly "how to format time" I guess user11124425 is french. `recuperate` is one of the translation for `recupérer`  which is used a lot when you say `I would like to (retrieve|get back) something` At least, in french the word it would make sense.

Comment: @cbaconnier: the format seems to be not good "Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Data missing " if you have another idea do not hesitate

Comment: @ cbaconnier: Yes, i am french... :-) When I tape on phpyMyAdmin une value of me field start_time for example 20:00 I would like to get 20:00 on my form index.blade.php

Comment: The @addWeb-solution-pvt-ltd should work then

Comment: @cbaconnier: it's doesn't works.. Never mind I will see after. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use `'start_time'` and `'end_time'` in date since they are not.

```
class Course extends Model
{
    protected $dates = ['date_seance'];
}
```

Then use

```
<td> {{$item->date_seance->format('d/m/Y') }}</td>
<td> {{date('H:i', strtotime($item->start_time)) }}</td>
<td> {{date('H:i', strtotime($item->end_time)) }}</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **Mutators** and **Accessors**.

1. A Mutator  `setStartTimeAttribute` to save time in database
2. An Accessor  `getStartTimeAttribute` to show it with required format i.e. `h:i or H:i`

   ```
   public function setStartDateAttribute($value)
   {
       $this->attributes['start_time'] = Carbon::parse($value)->format('H:i');
   }
   public function getStartDateAttribute()
   {
        return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['start_time'])->format('H:i');
   }
   ```

Now you can access formatted time as 
`$object->start_time` i.e. `20:00`

Answer (score 0):

the type of column is instance of Carbon class
what about trying this :

```
 <td> {{$item->date_seance->toDateString() }}</td>
```

Comment: Thank you but my problem is not date mais hour. I would like to get hour in fact.

Comment: i see ,did you try $item->start_time->format('h:i') ?

Answer (score 0):

try below format you already stored in time so no need to convert in strtotime

```
<td> {{date('H:i', $item->start_time) }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old but why not try a simple cast on model? Something like:

```
class Course extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'date_seance' => 'datetime:d/m/Y',
        'start_time'  => 'datetime:H:i',
        'toend_time' => 'datetime:H:i',
    ];
}
```

Check the docs here if you need more cast's types: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

```
<td> {{date('d/m/Y H:i', strtotime($item->date_seance)) }}</td>
```

Comment: thank you but date is already ok my problem is only hour in fact.